# ¿Por que el archivo bundle que subo a la google play store no funciona igual que el archivo apk que genero en flutter?

Tags: flutter, apk, bundler

Subí mi aplicación a la play store hace unos días y cuando se termino la revisión y ya la podía visualizar como oficial en la Google play store y la descargue para probarla como funcionaba, todo funcionaba bien pero después de unos días comencé a hacer algunas mejoras y a solucionar algunos errores que tenia, volví a generar el archivo bundle y lo subí a la play store en la sección de producción y ya cuando estaba visible la actualización el la play store actualice la app y entre para ver como funcionaba, casi todas las vistas que tenia aparecían en blanco solo la pantalla del menú se mostraba correctamente, me dirigí a la carpeta de la app ya que hay guardo algunos archivos y vi que no los crea, volví al código a checar que todo estuviera bien y genere un archivo apk para instalar la app en mi celular y funciona muy bien.

La forma en que genero el archivo bundle es:
1.- ejecuto el comando flutter clean
2.- ejecuto el comando flutter pub get
3.- ejecuto el comando flutter build appbundle --release

y ese es el proceso que sigo de igual manera antes de esto verifico que la versión del código sea diferente al archivo anterior para no tener problemas al subir a la play store.

espero alguien pueda ayudarme con esto.

Fecha de edicion: 16/02/2023

Ya solucioné el problema no estoy seguro por que fue pero creo que fue por que no modificaba la version de la app en el archivo `pubspec.yaml` y fue lo que afecto al subir los archivos a la play store, escuche que esto podia pasar en un video pero se me olvido y pues los problemas de no hacer ese paso.

La solución que hice fue hacer un nuevo proyecto en flutter pasar todo lo que tenia y hacer todo de cero en play store y firebase.

espero si a alguien le llega a pasar lo mismo esto le pueda ayudar.

Comment: ¿Probaste reinstalar la aplicación desde la tienda? Además Google Play te permite subir versiones de prueba justamente para evitar llevar errores a producción.

Comment: Hola mateo si la reinstale desde cero, reinicie el telefono y lo volvi a hacer y nada sigue igual, tambien lo probe en otro y lo mismo

Comment: En qué consiste tu aplicación ? Estás vistas muestran datos en base a peticiones ? Agrega más información.

Comment: Sin ver ninguna línea de código, es dificil ayudar ya que debemos de asumir todo, entonces no se puede dar una respuesta.

Comment: Las vistas funcionan con la información de los archivos pero si no hay información en los archivos las vistas simplemente muestran una nota con información por defecto y de igual manera si los archivos no existen las vistas se deberían de ver bien.

Answer (score 0):

El archivo bundle no deberia funcionar de manera diferente que el apk, el bundle es un tipo de archivo que Play Store puede sintetizar en apks especificas para cada dispositivo, optimizando la distribucion en tamaño de descarga como otras cuestiones para mas informacion esta la [documentacion](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle?hl=es-419) de Android Developers.

Veo que utilizas el build con --release y me cabe la duda si siguiste el proceso de preparacion para lanzamiento de la [documentacion](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android), mas que nada esta linea (en tu [project]/android/app/build.gradle):

```
 buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
```

También puedes probar con la opción que nos da Play Console que es "Prueba interna", es muy sencillo solamente añades verificadores o testers, ingresas tu bundle y la publicación para verificadores esta lista en unos minutos así puedes hacer iteraciones mas rápido y estar seguro de que tu bundle esta compilado con la funcionalidad que estas esperando. Mas información de pruebas internas:

[Documentacion](https://play.google.com/intl/es-419/console/about/internal-testing/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien antes de mandar tu aplicacion puedes probarla en modo release con el comando en tu terminal:

```
flutter run --release
```

Claro esta linea anterior si es que no tienes alguna necesidad mas, si te pide el dispositivo puedes buscar los id de tus dispositivos con:

```
flutter devices
```

Y lo agregarias asi:

```
flutter run --release -d 'id-dispositivo'
```

Esto por si tienes problema con permisos o demas detonantes que podrian surgir en lanzamiento.

Serviria que des mas detalles de tu build.gradle de tu manifest y de las principales funcionalidades para poderte apoyar de mejor manera.

Comment: No creo que tenga algo que ver usar una "prueba interna" con el problema. Lo que comentas al principio lo hace, de otra forma no podría subir la app a Google Play.

Comment: @Jorgesys Se lo comento para que pueda hacer iteraciones mas fáciles y saber si esta metiendo los cambios que necesita, porque puede ser que halla tenido errores de haber construido varias veces el bundle y haber seleccionado uno anterior, es una supocision, le puede ayudar a descartar, como lo comento en la respuesta, es rápido y practico

Comment: Cuando se sube un .APK o .AAB a Google Play no se permite subir uno anterior.

Comment: Seguí el proceso como dice la documentación y viendo videos para poder subir a la play store,  se me paso comentar que ya había hecho una actualización anterior mente y funciono bien, por eso es que me resulto extraño que en esta actualización pasara esto ya que no moví nada de lo que ya había configurado. Con respecto al build.gradle en esa lineal que comentas tengo una mas que es: `minifyEnabled true` no se si tenga algo que ver. y gracias por las sugerencias ya lo voy a empezar a hacer.

Comment: Acabo de usar el comando que mencionas `flutter run --release` y la app funciona correctamente como debería, pero cuando genero el bundle y lo subo a prueba interna y los descargo desde la play store en el celular ya no las vistas siguen en blanco y los archivos no se generan, cabe resaltar que agregue un widget en el `Scaffold` en la propiedad `endDrawer` que al deslizar el dedo sobre la pantalla desde la derecha a la izquierda este si se muestra pero la pantalla principal esta en blanco.